# How can PHP, JS, HTML and CSS files work together on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

Well, I am working on school project and I am doing social site. First I made my whole web-sites in HTML, CSS and JS. (including login and register section) Then I started to learn PHP and it looks like the PHP file is the separate website :/ (I don't know)

So the thing I want, is to have open my main page(html) and by some JS code, load or upload data from database(MySQL-phpMyAdmin) without opening another page(php file). Is it possible? I mean, I want the PHP codes to work like JS codes, in the background and don't open any window.

Sorry for the English

Comment: rename .html to .php, then enter php code between your other stuff. Looks like you need a better understanding of the server/client - model. By the way **login with JS????? Are you serious?**

Comment: Change your `HTML` extension to `PHP`.

Comment: You could look into [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), a javascript framework, to get a single page app that can communicate with PHP files that ultimately become API endpoints. For each task you could have php controller scripts that feed your front-end with data or stores data for you.

Comment: in extention to @Yolo : there are several single-page-application frameworks available, which looks like the thing you are searching for. A popular alternative to angularjs is [emberjs](https://emberjs.com/)

Comment: You should probably learn more about HTTP and how it works. Your web browser is basically an HTTP client which sends requests and receives responses to/from an HTTP server (generally Apache). If you want to interact with your server (and especially PHP code) without visiting another page, you may want to use Ajax which includes JavaScript and the XMLHttpRequest API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How a Server Request works:*

The client builds a packet, sends it to the server, the server builds a response packet and sends it back. The client opens the package and displays it.

```
Client -------- Request (just some bytes of data including GET and POST data ) -> Server
                <--- Response (HTML,CSS,JS) ---------------------------------------------------
```

But wheres the PHP? PHP is a **serverside** language. It tells the Server how to write the response package.
Therefore the client will never see it. PHP was designed to be just put somewhere in the other code, it is then parsed by the server.

```
*a Packet(HTML,CSS,JS and PHP)* -> PHP parser -> *a Packet without PHP* -> going to the Client
```

*Some Examples*

the code (*example.php*):

```
<html>
<title><?php echo "hi this is cool";?></title>
</html>
```

What the user will see:

```
<html>
<title>hi this is cool</title>
</html>
```

To set up this environment and a server, you may have a look at http://php.net, http://apache.org,*How to block ingoing data on my router?* , *how to set up wamp?* on the internet...

Answer (score 1):

PHP works at the server end and JS handles work at the client end. PHP can be used to generate HTML dynamically. Exmple different item lists or item contents.

I would recommend you to research more on the client server model.

Answering your question, Yes possible. It is called AJAX. (asynchronous JavaScript and XML). It is like talking to server through javascript without reloading the web page.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did the exact same thing as you.. personally, I find it easier to do everything using PHP files.
you still use HTML code.

you can either use

```
<?php 
echo "<div>";
?>
```

or without the PHP tags simply just use HTML.

```
"<div>"
```

PHP also allows you to import other files very easily.
the keyword "include" uses another file in the page that it is called.

this makes it very easy to build multiple pages with the same header, footer, CSS themes, database connection. whatever other PHP files you have.

```
<?php

 //   Description: Php, Html, css and javascript

echo "<html>";

include 'session.php'; // session php file is for session tracking
include 'header.php'; // header php file includes Css links.

?>

<body>
<h1>Title of the page<h1>

<p> This is where you would put the HTML code you wanted </p>

<?php

include 'footer.php'; // the footer div tag for the bottom of the page.
include 'bootstrapScript.php'; // file contains all bootstrap javascript links
include 'cookieConsent.php'; // file containing code for the cookie acceptance policies

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```